# Кэширование картинок на стороне браузера возможно ли?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть альбом с фотографиями, по определенному url. В обычной ситуации браузер почти каждый раз будет загружать фотографии заново. Можно ли фото сохранить на стороне пользователя физически? И в Javascript подставлять ссылку на локальное хранилище(куки для картинок)?

Есть конечно http-equiv="Cache-Control", но он кэширует весь документ. У меня такая task, что мне как раз нельзя кэшировать весь документ - только определенные фото. Возможно ли такое сделать?

Comment: В настройках сервера можно задать кэширование статических данных на какое-то время (например на неделю) и картинка будет храниться у клиента до тех пор, пока не истечет время или пользователь не очистит кэш, ссылки менять не надо, файлы из кэша браузер берет сам. Настройки зависят от того, какой у вас сервер.

Comment: Картинки и так кешируются браузером.

Comment: В настройках сервера, можно задать разные настройки кеширования для одной или другой папки.

Comment: @And, т.е. вообще ничего можно не делать? В папке гугловского кэша картинки будут? А если связь с интернетом оборвется, они будут показываться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Решение

Кеширование определенных картинок в `javascript` возможен, но обычно браузер кеширует все картинки, которые были прогружены.

Но тем не менее, если вы хотите использовать кеширование определенных картинок средствами `javascript`:

```js
"use strict";

var imageCache = new function() {
  var me = this;

  var cache = [];
  var root = document.location.href.split("/");

  root.pop();
  root = root.join("/") + "/";

  me.push = function(src, loadEvent) {
    if (!src.match(/^http/)) {
      src = root + src;
    }

    var item = new Image();

    if (cache[src] && loadEvent) {
      loadEvent(src);
    } else {
      if (loadEvent) {
        item.onload = loadEvent;
        item.onerror = loadEvent;
      }
      cache[src] = item;
    }

    item.src = src;
  };

  me.pushArray = function(array, imageLoadEvent, imagesLoadEvent) {
    var numLoaded = 0;
    var arrayLength = array.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
      me.push(array[i], function(e) {
        if (imageLoadEvent) {
          imageLoadEvent(e);
        }
        numLoaded++;
        if (numLoaded == arrayLength) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            imagesLoadEvent(e);
          }, 1);
        }
      });
    }
  };
}();

var s = ["https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/88/Half-Life_Black_Mesa_logo.svg", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5d/Clojure_logo.svg", "https://4hands.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/viber-logo-256x256.png"];
imageCache.pushArray(s, () => console.log('when one of all images has been loaded'), () => console.log('when all images have been loaded'));
```

Если запустите данных код в консоли браузера, то увидите, что картинки попали в кеш:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если вы не хотите кешировать все файлы в браузере, можете использовать `meta`- теги:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

Comment: супер, то что нужно! спасибо.

Comment: @Anonymous пожалуйста!